# Poner valor de una variable en el max="" de un input

Tags: php, html, input, tabla-dinámica, maxima

Mi formulario esta en una tabla y cada celda contiene un input.

Tengo un input cantidad:

```
cell3.innerHTML = `<input  max="" name="cantidad[]"  required class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-sm-3 col-md-12" type="number" min="0"  list="cantidades">
    <datalist id="cantidades">

        <option value="10">

        <option value="100">

        <option value="1000">

        <option value="10000">

    </datalist> <div class="invalid-feedback"> Debe elegir una cantidad </div>`;;
```

Quiero que tenga un `max=""` a partir de un valor(`unidades_disponibles`) que sale de la consulta:

```
$consulta_producto = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT codigo , nombre, precio as 'precio_unitario', unidades_disponibles  FROM tblproductoterminado  where fecha_vencimiento > NOW()  ");
```

Para ello recorro la consulta antes del input y llamo el campo en el `max=""`:

```
<?php $cant = $consulta_producto->fetch_assoc(); ?> //recorriendo la consulta

    cell3.innerHTML = `<input  max="<?php echo $cant[unidades_disponibles]?>" name="cantidad[]"  required class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-sm-3 col-md-12" type="number" min="0"  list="cantidades">
    <datalist id="cantidades">

        <option value="10">

        <option value="100">

        <option value="1000">

        <option value="10000">

    </datalist> <div class="invalid-feedback"> Debe elegir una cantidad </div>`;;
```

No me da resultado. Cuando escribo un valor mayor a `unidades_disponibles` se  valida correctamente cosa que no debe hacer.

Comment: el HTML generado si es el que esperas? no sé porque creo que no estás accediendo a la variable `unidades_disponibles` como es... podrías poner el resultado de lo que te genera en el html? o en su defecto poner el resultado de `var_dump($cant);`

Comment: @Pipe  si pongo -var_dump- no muestra nada